# Fixed DataStringFormat GirdView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, formatting

Is there a way how to format a number in gridview with fixed currency format? I use

```
DataFormatString="{0:C}"
```

but since my page is available in multiple languages it also changes currency signs. Is there a way how to apply format to column like this?

```
"C0",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture('en-US')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will need something similar there is a solution

```
protected void grdReport_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            Decimal dec;
            if (Decimal.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[1].Text, out dec))
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = dec.ToString("C0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("cs-CZ"));
        }
```

I need only display those number so this is ok for me. In case you need to work with them you need to split the text and then convert it to number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change the data format by transform when get the data, no when show them. If you parse the data to string in the format that you want you don't need to transform in the server. For example if you are using sql server you can format by the view.

If this is noy what you expect write me in a comment.

Thanks

Comment: I was thinking about some format changes in OnRowDataBound event.

Comment: or in paint method too you can change the format in the cell paint method. Caution with the way of format this because when you save the data you have the problem in the other direction

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the Culture for that page and even define a custom currency symbol if needed.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US")
{
    NumberFormat = { CurrencySymbol = "%" }               
};
```

Comment: But this will apply to whole page I guess. I am tyring to format column of gridview in a specific way regardles of page Culture or UICulture (because culture settings works perfectly fine for other parts of the page).